# How to compress file in non-blocking way

Tags: c++, file, compression

My application has a class that has a method that writes to a file using std::ofstream.

It's a multithreaded app and many threads can call the log() function at the same time. Therefore, I have added a std::lock_guard mutex in the log() function.

These threads can be transient too, which means it's not necessary that they are going to live as long as the parent process lives.

Once the file size reaches the maximum configured value, it should be renamed and compressed.

The file size can be as big as 1GB. And gzip takes more than 20 seconds to compress that.

Therefore the thread is blocked until gzip finishes compressing.

I'm looking for a way in which the file can be compressed in non-blocking way keeping the std::lock_guard guard(_log_mutex); in mind.

```
class Logger {
    std::string   _logfile;
    std::mutex    _log_mutex;
    uint64_t      _sequence_number;
    std::ofstream::pos_type _curr_size;

 public:
    void log (std::string message)
    {
        // Take the lock
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_log_mutex);

        // If size exceeds max then close, rename, and compress.
        if (_curr_size >= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            _outputFile.close();

            // Code already in place to rename the file.

            // Compress _logfile ???

            _outputFile.open(_logfile, std::ios::app);
            _curr_size = _outputFile.tellp();
        }

        _outputFile << _sequence_number << " : " << message << std::endl;
        _outputFile.flush();
        _curr_size = _outputFile.tellp();
        _sequence_number++;
    }

    // Other stuffs...
    ...
};
```

I tried following but it still blocks the thread:

```
compress_file(const char *file_name) {
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (!pid) {
        execl("/usr/bin/gzip", "gzip", "-f", file_name, NULL);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while (wait3(NULL, WNOHANG, NULL) > 0) {
          ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should rename the file before starting an asynchronous compression and open a new one for the incoming logs

Comment: In addition to what @OznOg said, you could do the compression in an extra thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Take the lock
- Close the stream
- Rename the file
- Reopen stream
- Release the lock
- Compress the renamed file without blocking the writers